# Can the hadoop pipes be run using the driver code?

Tags: hadoop

I know that hadoop pipes can be run using the command line interface like [this](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/C%2B%2BWordCount).
But can we call the pipes program just like we call the java based mapreduce job using driver like [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#driver) example ?

EDIT : I am doing some image processing operations in my C++ code.

Comment: You want to reuse C++ code (or binary) and use it from Java code?

Comment: I have written a program in C++ implementing my own mapper and reducer class. In mapper I am reusing the c functions which were written long back. 
I am running this program using CLI. 
`hadoop pipes -input path/to/input -output path/to/output -program bin/myprgram`
Can I run it using the driver code? like [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#driver)

Comment: If you want to use driver code then you have to write Java versions of your mapper and reduce classes. You can call your old C functions using Java Native Interface (JNI).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
But I was wondering which approach is better?
Calling C functions using JNI or using hadoop pipes?

Comment: Why do you even want to use the driver code if you already have a working solution?